# Need help optimizing MPI parallelized Gaussian elimination algorithm С++

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

I am currently working on a project where I need to parallelize the Gaussian elimination algorithm using MPI in C++. I have already implemented the algorithm, but I'm facing performance issues when calling the parallel version of the `gaussianMPI` function. Surprisingly, the sequential version of `gaussian` works faster than the parallel one.

One of the approaches I am considering is to call the `gaussianMPI` function from the main thread instead of creating a separate MPI process. However, I am not sure how to do this or if it is even possible with MPI.

I want the functions themselves to be called in the main thread, but according to the documentation, it seems impossible with MPI. In my case, the function `gaussianMPI` is called for each thread.

Can anyone suggest how to optimize the parallel Gaussian elimination algorithm or propose alternative approaches to improve its performance?
I need to confine the scope of MPI parallelism within the for loop, but idk how to do it.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
const int N = 3; // Dimension of the matrix
const int rowsPerProc = 1; // For each process, N/size rows
void gaussianMPI(double A[N][N + 1], int rank, int local_rows) {
    int i, j, k;
    double koef;
    double aa[1][N + 1];
    // Forward elimination
    for (k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
        MPI_Bcast(A, (N-1) * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Scatter(A, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, aa, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (i = 0; i < local_rows; i++) {
            if (rank * local_rows + i > k) {
                koef = aa[i][k] / A[k][k];
                for (j = k; j < N + 1; j++) {
                    aa[i][j] -= koef * A[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Gather(aa, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, A, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    // Back substitution
    for (k = N - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (rank== 0) {
            A[k][N] /= A[k][k];
            A[k][k] = 1.0;
        }
        MPI_Bcast(A, N * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Scatter(A, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, aa, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (i = 0; i < local_rows; i++) {
            if (rank * local_rows + i < k) {
                aa[i][N] -= A[rank * local_rows + i][k] * A[k][N];
                aa[i][k] = 0.0;
            }
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Gather(aa, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, A, local_rows * (N + 1), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    // Output results on rank 0 process
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << A[i][N] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void gaussian(double A[N][N + 1]) {
    int i, j, k;
    double koef;
    // Forward elimination
    for (k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
        for (i = k + 1; i < N; i++) {
            koef = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
            for (j = k; j < N + 1; j++) {
                A[i][j] -= koef * A[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    // Back substitution
    for (k = N - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        A[k][N] /= A[k][k];
        A[k][k] = 1.0;
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            A[i][N] -= A[i][k] * A[k][N];
            A[i][k] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << A[i][N] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    double A[N][N + 1] = { {1, 2, -1, 2}, {2, -3, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 1, 8} };
    double B[N][N + 1]  = { {1, 2, -1, 2}, {2, -3, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 1, 8} };

    int rank, size;
    double start_time, end_time;
    MPI_Init(0, 0);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int local_rows = N / size;

    if (rank == 0)  start_time = clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    gaussianMPI(B, rank, local_rows);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0) {
        end_time = clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "Total time taken by the program is " << end_time - start_time << " seconds" << endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    if (rank == 0) {
        start_time = clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        gaussian(A);
        end_time = clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "Total time taken by the program is " << end_time - start_time << " seconds" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Often a question like this is better suited to Code Review. Code Review is for code that works, but could be made to work better, but when it comes to not meeting performance requirements, sometimes that's a bug and other times it's a sign that you need to junk the algorithm and go for something better suited to your needs. While I know the former isn't covered by Code Review's mandate and needs to be asked here, I'm not sure about the later.

Comment: @user4581301 Not so much. Performance questions like this is on-topic here (and actually better here IMHO) since the OP want only to focus on performance and provides a MRE, though the post could be more focused and could also include timings / profiling details. See [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review) for more information.

Comment: This program has undefined behavior. If you use g++ or clang++, compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` to get the full story at runtime. There's no use trying to optimize it before it actually has defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why your code will not give good performance.

1. You seem to have the full matrix on each process, but then each process seems to update only local information. You are really assuming shared memory. Instead distributed your matrix. Maybe you're compensating for this by the scatter, but that is a big time waste, and probably the reason that your parallel code is slower.
2. With a distributed matrix, the broadcast of the pivot column needs to originate from the process owning that column.
3. Your barrier does nothing. Remove it. Barriers are never needed, except for timing.
4. And most importantly, the only way to get efficient Gaussian elimination is to have a cyclic distribution of the your rows. But that comes after point 1. where I tell you to distribute the data to begin with.
5. And of course your matrix needs to have a size in the many thousands. For `N=3` the work is basically nothing, and your communication is equivalent to millions of operations.

Comment: I understand about the matrix size, but for testing purposes, I've been using a size of 3. Regarding the cyclic distribution of rows, could you provide some guidance on how that could be implemented?

Comment: Row `i` goes to processor `i%p` where `p` the number of processors. You actually want to do that blocked, so `i` goes to `(i/b)%p`. And then you want to do that for both `i` and `j`. And that's why almost no one has written an alternative to Scalapack. See only PLapack & Elemental.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to do it slightly differently and encountered a problem:How to synchronize rows, for example, process with rank 0 processed row 0, process with rank 1 processed row 1, process with rank 2 processed row 2, etc. After iterating over k, I want to update matrix A on each process. How can I do this?

Comment: `int start = rank * local_rows;
int end = start + local_rows ;
for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
  if (i> k) {
   double koef = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
   for (int j = k; j < N + 1; j++) {
    A[i][j] -= koef * A[k][j];
   }
  }
 }
 //Need sync here 
}`